# As.Date - charToDate(x)

Tags: r, date

Can anyone explain this behavior to me please. I seem to be confused here.
Why is "2013-12-31" valid, but not "2013-11-31" ?

```
as.Date("2013-11-31")
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
as.Date("2013-12-31")
[1] "2013-12-31"
```

And:

```
as.Date("2013-11-31",format="%Y-%m-%d")
[1] NA
as.Date("2013-12-31",format="%Y-%m-%d")
[1] "2013-12-31"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe because Nov only has 30 days...?

Comment: lol. That is true. There was some date errors in the data, and I did not even reflect about it.

Comment: @spesseh or using `lubridate` you can do `ymd("2013-11-31")`.